# How to test void method that only modifies private class member variables?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm trying to unit test a method in a class that initializes some private fields:

```
public void init(Properties props) throws Exception {

    this.language = props.getProperty(Constants.LANGUAGE,Constants.LANGUAGE_DEFAULT);   
    this.country = props.getProperty(Constants.COUNTRY,Constants.COUNTRY_DEFAULT);

        try {
            this.credits = Integer.valueOf(props.getProperty(Constants.CREDITS_OPTION_NAME, Constants.CREDITS_DEFAULT_VALUE));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid configuration: 'credits' does not contain a valid integer value.", e);
        }
        //rest of method removed for sake of simplicity
    }
```

My dilemma is that I want to assert that the language, country and credits fields have been set after calling init, however they are private with no public accessor methods. I see there are two solutions for testing this:

1. Make public methods for accessing the private fields, then call these methods after testing the init method.
2. Make the unit test just call init method, and assume everything worked correctly is no exception was thrown.

What do you think is the ideal way to test this method?

Comment: Is there a reason nobody suggested adding another test that calls the setter, then calls "another method in the same class that needs these fields to be set?" I'm pretty new to TDD and had been leaning towards this kind of solution in my own work, is there a problem with it? Is it still unit testing, or something else, like integration testing or something? as appears to be suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193257/should-i-test-public-class-function-that-changes-only-internal-state-of-the-obje

Answer (score 10):

> I want to assert that the language, country and credits fields have been set after calling init

Some philosophy: why do you care whether they are set correctly? If the answer is "so the class then behaves correctly", then you can test that they have been set correctlty by testing that expected subsequent behaviour. If however setting them incorrectly has no effect they are redundant and you should remove them.

Another poster has suggested using reflection to access the private fields. I advise against this; anything marked private should be an implementation detail of the class, and therefore should not be directly tested. You should instead test the published API of your class. You then have the freedom to refactor it easilly by changing implementation (private) details.

Comment: There is another method in the same class that needs these fields to be set, however since the method call that relies on these fields is mocked it won't be reporting an error. In this case is it better to catch the fields as they are being set in the init method?

Comment: If no error would be reported, the fields have no effect, so I would recommend removing them Or, rather, defer adding them until you work on that method.

Comment: Under normal circumstances there would be an error reported, but under a test situation those external dependencies need to be mocked - hence no error would be thrown from the mock - but the fields are actually required. Setting the field values only in the method they are used in would make sense, but the values they are set from (props) are only available to the init method.

Comment: You are saying that it is hard to test your class. This suggests the design of your class is faulty, and you need to adjust the published interface of the class to make it easier to test.

Answer (score 9):

You can use reflection to get the values of private fields. For example:

```
Field field = YourClass.class.getDeclaredField("language");
field.setAccessible(true); //override the access restriction of it being private
field.get(yourObject);
```

If there's spring on your classpath, you can use its `ReflectionUtils` / `ReflectionTestUtils`.

It is sometimes argued that private fields should not be verified, and only the public state of the object is the point of unit-testing. From that perspective it may be better to expose a getter, or even better - thrown an exception.

If the object is in invalid state if the fields are not set, then it should be the responsibility of the object itself to enforce its validity, by throwing an exception.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I decided to throw an exception from my init method if the values were not correct.

Answer (score 4):

I usually try to avoid tests that depend on the internal structure of the class under test. I'd much rather test this by testing some method that then uses these fields.

If you're doing strict TDD, you shouldn't even add those fields until you have a test case that actually takes advantage of them :)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unit testing legacy code, so I don't have much freedom on the changes I can make.

Comment: +1 for "you shouldn't even add those fields until you have a test case"

Answer (score 1):

Does your JUnit call the method directly? Then the reference to the Property Object is the same, you should be able to access Language and Country, for credits do the recalculation in your JUnit.

Public accessor for private methods is also a good choice.

Comment: Public accessor methods would work, but then I am exposing the field values from outside the class when they don't need to be visible. I'm all for refactoring code to make it more testable but this doesn't seem "right" in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would just check the public methods.  Sometimes you need to check the internals, but this is rare.

BTW: An alternative to public getters is to make the unit test in the same package and provide package local getters.